# React Native - how to make a border image?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a border image to a `View` , similar to [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) in the css.

How could I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if you use Styled Components (https://www.styled-components.com/) you can set it with CSS directly. It will be something like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const StyledView = styled.View`
  border-image: <your definition here>;
`;
```

And then simply use it like you always do:

```
<StyledView>

</StyledView>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was not able to run the preview but here you go: https://snack.expo.io/B1e7glEJQ

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) component of react-native and wrap your view inside component by adding some padding around your nested view

```
<ImageBackground source={imageSource}>
 <Text style={{padding:20}}> Inside </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an image that contains your border as the first element  of your view and some padding on the contents of the view.

```
<Image
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#ccc',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
        source={{ uri: 'path/to/your/image/of/border' }}
>

<Text
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 30,
            padding: 40,
          }}
        >
          {text}
</Text>
```