# How to add border-image in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

How do I add an image border like this CSS in react native?

```
img {
  border: 20px solid black;
  border-image: url("xyzborderimage.jpg") 30 round;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 250;          
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - how to make a border image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343640/react-native-how-to-make-a-border-image)

Comment: no, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View Style Props with prefix name border, for example `borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red', borderRadius: 8` you can read more on this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props